# Why does combining these if statements result in higher logic element utilization?

Tags: verilog, fpga, intel-fpga

I have a project in verilog where I'm keeping track of the date. I have the following code to handle the different length of months, unless I am mistaken I can combine these all by oring each condition and just having one if statement. This however will result in using 1 more LE. Why?

```
        if( ( months == 4 || months == 6 || months == 9 || months == 11 ) && days == 31 && set_state == 0 ) begin
            months = months + 1;
            days = 1;
        end
        else if( months == 2 && years[1:0] == 0 && days == 30 && set_state == 0 ) begin
            months = months + 1;
            days = 1;
        end
        else if( months == 2 && years[1:0] != 0 && days == 29 && set_state == 0 ) begin
            months = months + 1;
            days = 1;
        end
        else if( days == 32 ) begin
            months = months + 1;
            days = 1;               
        end
```

EDIT: This is what uses the additional LE

```
    if( ( ( months == 4 || months == 6 || months == 9 || months == 11 ) && days == 31 && set_state == 0 ) ||
        ( months == 2 && years[1:0] == 0 && days == 30 && set_state == 0 ) ||
        ( months == 2 && years[1:0] != 0 && days == 29 && set_state == 0 ) ||
        ( days == 32 ) ) begin
        months = months + 1;
        days = 1;
    end
```

Comment: Btw you can use this to check the months from march to december. `months > 2 && days > 32 - ((months - 3) % 5 % 2)`

Comment: I don't know how you can consider either of those; they're both completely unmaintainable.  It would be so much simpler with a temporary variable for `length_of_this_month`.

Comment: If they are truly logically equivalent (I haven't had time to check!), I would raise a bug with the tool vendor

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The two statements are logically equivalent [using the following Boolean law](http://nayuki.eigenstate.org/page/boolean-algebra-laws):

```
A | (~A & B) = A | B
```

I think it has to do with the synthesis tool logic minimization algorithm that does not synthesize exactly the same circuits, although they are logically equivalent.

Comment: @Philippe: I wrote OP's statement as: `if (C1) P else if (C2) P else if (C3) P else if (C4) P` which is equivalent to: `if (C1 | ~C1 & C2 | ~C1 & ~C2 & C3 | ~C1 & ~C2 & ~C3 & C4) P`. This can be simplified to `if (C1 | C2 | C3 | C4) P`. What am I missing?